# Why is this Chrome extension loading twice?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, bookmarklet

Bookmarklet is supposed to load a pop-up (bookmarklet.js) alone, instead when clicked the extension opens the bookmarklet in the current tab AND as a pop-up.

background.html file:

```
<script>
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "bookmarklet.js"})
});
</script>
```

bookmarklet.js file:

```
var d=document,w=window,e=w.getSelection,k=d.getSelection,x=d.selection,s=(e?e():(k)?      k():(x? x.createRange().text:0)),f='http://www.quora.com/board/bookmarklet',l=d.location,e=encodeURIComponent,p='?v=1&url='+e(l.href),u=f+p;try{if(!/^(.*\.)?quora[^.]*$/.test(l.host))throw(0);}catch(z){a =function(){if(!w.open(u,'_blank','toolbar=0,scrollbars=no,resizable=1,status=1,width=430,height=400'))l.href=u;};if(/Firefox/.test(navigator.userAgent))setTimeout(a,0);else a();}void(0o)
```

Answer (score 3):

You should set the popup html file location in the `manifest.json` file. The popup file can contain the script from `bookmarklet.js`. Then no more script on `background.html` is needed, because `onClicked`  will not fire if the browser action has a popup. The popup will appear itself when the extension icon is clicked. Or, you can as well use the `setPopup()` method.

Everything described [here](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/browserAction.html#popups)